# SocketInputStream.socketRead0 occupies 30% of application time

Tags: spring, performance, sockets, jboss, profiling

High-throughput application is deployed in JBoss 7 which processes over 200k requests per minute. The application reads http requests and processes them. Average request payload size is 1.5Kb.

A cpu thread profiler shows the following:

55% time: `Unsafe.park` (threads waiting to be assigned?)
30% time: `SocketInputStream.socketRead0` (probably reading requests off the socket?)
8% time: entire application code for processing requests
4% time: Spring code

Can someone throw some light on why so much time might is spent in `Unsafe.park` and `SocketInputStream.socketRead0`? As per other stackoverflow posts, `Unsafe.park` maybe threads waiting to be assigned, representing reserve capacity (not sure of this). The remaining 45% is probably the actual used capacity.

The most surprising part is that `SocketInputStream.socketRead0` (thread dump stack frames below) occupies as much as 30% of the time. While processing requests which is the entire complex application code including multiple network lookups occupies only 8% of the time.

If you consider only the 45% used capacity, `SocketInputStream.socketRead0` takes 67% of the time.

The main question is what might be causing `SocketInputStream.socketRead0` to take so much time? Any pointers will help.

The thread dump shows the following stack trace frames for `SocketInputStream.socketRead0`

```
org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run() :122
java.lang.Thread.run() :745
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run() :835,825,840,842
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor, java.lang.Runnable) :45
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(java.lang.Runnable) :801
org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) :33
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() :520,518
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(java.net.Socket) :671
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(java.net.Socket) :838,877,904,844
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine() :369,368
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill() :731
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) :122
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) :152
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) :native
```

Stack frames for `Unsafe.park`:

```
org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run() :122
java.lang.Thread.run() :745
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run() :835,825,840,842
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$400(org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor) :45
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.takeTask() :746
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() :2039,2043
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) :186
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) :native
```

Stack frames invoking application code:

```
org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run() :122
java.lang.Thread.run() :745
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run() :835,825,840,842
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor, java.lang.Runnable) :45
org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(java.lang.Runnable) :801
org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) :33
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() :520,518
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(java.net.Socket) :671
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(java.net.Socket) :838,877,904,844
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(org.apache.coyote.Request, org.apache.coyote.Response) :395,368,364,365
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) :109
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) :123,131,102
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) :125,143,185,155
org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) :159,155,93,153,72,86,158,92,83,109
org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke :50,47
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) :161
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) :283,253,275
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) :248
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) :280
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) :76,74,-1,67,83
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain) :88
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) :248
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) :329
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) :848,-1,847
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) :754,781
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) :789
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) :867,920,873,882,866,919,870
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) :842,848,840,849,839,852,841
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) :886,934,923,963,893,910,-1,984,914
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.lang.Object) :80,-1
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod) :578
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod) :621,610,606,-1,609,608,617,612,614,618
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest, org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer, java.lang.Object[]) :96
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest, org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer, java.lang.Object[]) :126,117
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(java.lang.Object[]) :213
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) :606
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) :43
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor405.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])
com.myco.myapp.AppController.process(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.io.Writer, @RequestHeader java.lang.String, @PathVariable java.lang.String, @RequestParam java.lang.String) :84,83,82
```

**EDIT (Apr 8):**
Well it looks like the above stack frames for the 30% `socketRead0` are for only reading the "request line", not the request body. See above

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine() :369,368
```

Turns out the "request body" is actually being read from the 8% application code and is taking 1.7% (which still seems higher than it should take) of the overall time. Continuation of the above stack frames invoking application code to show request body being read:

```
com.myco.myapp.AppController.process(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, java.io.Writer, @RequestHeader java.lang.String, @PathVariable java.lang.String, @RequestParam java.lang.String) :84,83,82
com.myco.myapp.AppController.getRequestBody(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.lang.String) :229,221,222,-1
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.readLine() :190,203,158,201,192,204
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.read(char[], int, int) :105
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(char[], int, int) :447
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.substract(char[], int, int) :445
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadChars(char[], int, int) :398
org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(byte[], int, int) :347
org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk) :438
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.doRead(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk, org.apache.coyote.Request) :706
org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk, org.apache.coyote.Request) :116
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk, org.apache.coyote.Request) :777
org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill() :747
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(multiple parameter matches) :-1,122
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) :152
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) :native
```

Questions are is still the same:
1. Why 30% time spent in `socketRead0`?
2. Why 55% in `Unsafe.park`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. As per the [Thread Profiler documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/events/thread-profiler-tool#viewing):

> After the profiler finishes running, the agent will report the profile data. The call tree automatically appears on the Thread profiler page. The percentages in the call tree represent the percentage of thread backtrace samples in which each call path appeared during the profiling session.

The New Relic thread profiler works by sampling. The percentages are not the amount of time spent, but simply the percentage of samples in which the method appeared.

Transactions is the function which shows which methods are the most time-consuming. Docs [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/monitoring/transactions-page).